# Populating ComboBox with dynamic values from another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

---Update---

Thanks for the responses, I have found that DragonSamu's updated answer works perfectly.

---

---Original Post---

I have been trying to figure out where I am going wrong for the past few hours but I can't spot it. I think it's because the script is trying to draw the value from the active worksheet which is not what I want. Hopefully somebody can put me on the rite track - I think the answer should be relatively obvious but I just can't see it!

Basically, I am trying to populate a Combobox with a dynamic range of values that exist in another worksheet (but in the same workbook).  I can get the Combobox to populate when I run the script in the worksheet 'Materials' (which is where the dynamic list is drawn from) but not when I run it in the worksheet 'Products'.

Unfortunately the script is designed to populate Products with Materials so is be run in a UserForm when the 'Products' worksheet is open and the 'Materials' worksheet would therefore be inactive.

I should also note that this script has been adapted from code I found elsewhere on this forum, so if it seems familiar I thank you in advance :)

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim rRange As Range

On Error GoTo ErrorHandle

'We set our range = the cell B7 in Materials
Set rRange = Worksheets("Materials").Range("B7")

'Check if the cell is empty
If Len(rRange.Formula) = 0 Then
   MsgBox "The list is empty"
   GoTo BeforeExit
End If

'Finds the next empty row and expands rRange
If Len(rRange.Offset(1, 0).Formula) > 0 Then
   Set rRange = Range(rRange, rRange.End(xlDown))
End If

'The range's address is our rowsource
Mat1_Name_ComBox.RowSource = rRange.Address
Mat2_Name_ComBox.RowSource = rRange.Address
Mat3_Name_ComBox.RowSource = rRange.Address
Mat4_Name_ComBox.RowSource = rRange.Address
Mat5_Name_ComBox.RowSource = rRange.Address

BeforeExit:
Set rRange = Nothing
Exit Sub
ErrorHandle:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume BeforeExit

End Sub
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Cheers,

Simon

Comment: Where does the code give an error?

Comment: The code doesn't actually throw an error, which is partially why is has been confusing me so much.  The Combobox just does not populate when the Products worksheet is active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see your code would be giving an error here:

```
If Len(rRange.Offset(1, 0).Formula) > 0 Then
    Set rRange = Range(rRange, rRange.End(xlDown))
End If
```

Because your trying to set `rRange` by using `Range()` without defining the `Worksheet` first. This will get the `Range` from the `ActiveWorksheet`.

change it to the following:

```
If Len(rRange.Offset(1, 0).Formula) > 0 Then
    Set rRange = Worksheets("Materials").Range(rRange, rRange.End(xlDown))
End If
```

best practice would be the following:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim wb as Workbook
Dim sh as Worksheet
Dim rRange As Range

On Error GoTo ErrorHandle

'Set the Workbook and Worksheet
set wb = Workbooks("products.xlsx")
set sh = wb.Worksheets("Materials")

'We set our range = the cell B7 in Materials
Set rRange = sh.Range("B7")

'Check if the cell is empty
If Len(rRange.Formula) = 0 Then
   MsgBox "The list is empty"
   GoTo BeforeExit
End If

'Finds the next empty row and expands rRange
If Len(rRange.Offset(1, 0).Formula) > 0 Then
   Set rRange = sh.Range(rRange, rRange.End(xlDown))
End If
```

By properly defining and setting your `Workbook` and `Worksheet` you correctly reference to them and don't get errors.

Update:

the 2nd problem is that `rRange.Address` only places the `Range` location inside your `.RowSource` not the `Sheet` it needs to look at.

change:

```
Mat1_Name_ComBox.RowSource = rRange.Address
```

to:

```
dim strSheet as String
strSheet = "Materials"
Mat1_Name_ComBox.RowSource = strSheet + "!" + rRange.Address
```

This way it will include the `Sheet` name into the `.RowSource`

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately same issue still persists (although it has made my code nicer).  

The Combobox populates with the Materials values when the Materials worksheet is active (it shows all of the entries from B7 down) but does not populate with the Materials values when the Products worksheet is active.  

I have since tried inserting values into the cells B7 to B10 in the Products worksheet and these are now displayed when the Products worksheet is active.  

So it would appear that it is still looking referencing the active page. To clarify, both are worksheets in one workbook.

Comment: @SimonColebrook Its 2 fold, got the 2nd problem now will update my answer

Comment: You could just use `Mat1_Name_ComBox.RowSource = rRange.Address(External:=True)`.  Another method would be to populate the combo's list with the range's array: `Mat1_Name_ComBox.List = rRange.Value`